# Can the ActionBar drop-down navigation list be customized to include an icon?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

Can the drop-down navigation list in an ActionBar be modified to include an icon on its left-hand side? Basically I want an icon alongside the action bar entry itself, and not on the individual list items.

Thanks in advance, Peter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You supply the `SpinnerAdapter` for use with the drop-down navigation list. Choose an appropriate resource for the closed state (i.e., the resource you supply to the `ArrayAdapter` constructor), one that has your desired icon in the desired position.

Comment: I tried to create an ArrayAdapter using 'new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(activity, R.layout.sort, R.id.sorttext, sortData);' where 'sorttext' is a TextView ID in the layout but get an exception stating that the ArrayAdapter requires a TextView ID. Should I also need to override getView? Am I right in thinking that the view returned by getView(...) is the closed view? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry ignore previous comment regarding exception as I've now resolved this.